# Once value increments digits stops working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function so say i have a list:

1. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

and if i click say number 3 , number 3 gets removed and all the values larger than this value will be taken away by one so it'd end up looking like this:

1. 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8

The only problem is that once we start going into the tenths the function just does not work for example if i had:

1. 8,9,10,11,12,13

its meant to look like if i took 9 like:

1. 8,9,10,11,12

but it goes like this:

1. 8,10,11,12

completely ignorning once we get to double figures.... heres what i have:

```
$("button").each(function(){
    if (pad2(cl_on)<pad2($(this).val())){
        $(this).val($(this).val()-1);
    }
```

});

i did have a fix for this going upto 99 but once i go over to 100 onwards the same problem resurects, this is the function i have to fix it upto 99...

> function pad2(number) {
>        return (number < 10 ? "0" : "") + number }

There must be something wrong with even having to use this function... can someone help me so i dont have this problem again say if i reach 1000 or 10000?

Comment: You say "if i click say number 3 all the values larger than this value will be taken away", but surely then if you click 3 you'll be left with the list `1,2,3`? But you're left with lots of numbers bigger than 3?

Comment: *I have a function so say i have a list* What?  *if i click say number 3 all the values larger (...) will be taken away*  So why was only 9 removed? Your question is not clear. But from what I see is that you compare strings and not numbers,  `'10' < '2'` but `2 < 10`, and that seems to be your problem.

Comment: so number 3 gets removed and then all values larger than 3 get taken away by 1... sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Felix said, or use parseInt() to achieve the same;

```
$("button").each(function(){
    if (parseInt(cl_on, 10) < parseInt($(this).val(), 10)){
        $(this).val(parseInt($(this).val(), 10) - 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to numbers, e.g. using unary `+`. You can also simplify your code to:

```
$("button").val(function(i, val) {
    return +cl_on < +val ? val - 1 : val;
});
```

As I said in my comment, you are comparing strings, and in lexical(?) order, `10` comes before `2` for example.